# Try Parse GUID - Issues with a Valid GUID

Tags: c#, .net

I have had some issues in the past while parsing GUID's When dealing with cross platforms the short hyphens sometimes get replaced by long ones. resulting in a failed parse attempt on what looks like a perfectly valid GUID.

So how would we go about solving this?

Answer (score 7):

If you're worried about unusual characters appearing in your GUID, looking for and replacing a *single* type of unusual character might not be enough. The following will remove *anything* that's not a hexadecimal character:

```
var sanitisedGuid = Regex.Replace(unsanitisedGuid, "[^A-Fa-f0-9]", string.Empty);
// not A-Za-z, thanks @thakrage
```

This should leave just the characters that are absolutely necessary for the GUID, which you can then parse with the `"N"` format specifier:

```
if (Guid.TryParseExact(sanitisedGuid, "N", out guid))
    ...
```

This won't help if one of these letters or numbers is itself a [homoglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph), though.

```
var unsanitisedGuid = "аbϲԁеf-0123456789-0123456789-012345";
```

*looks* perfectly valid but isn't.

Comment: Guids in C# are hexadecimal, so `[^A-Za-z0-9]` would actually allow illegal characters through

Answer (score 3):

If you strip any undesired characters out completely then you can still parse the guid. The hyphens are mainly for visual formatting and not part of the data so .NET can parse a string without the hyphens very easily. This means that you can if you want strip out all non alphanumeric characters before parsing and it should parse fine.

Here is a proof of concept program.

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
Regex re = new Regex("[^a-fA-F0-9]");
Console.WriteLine(guid.ToString());
var stripped = re.Replace(guid.ToString(),"");
Console.WriteLine(stripped);
Guid newGuid;
if (Guid.TryParse(stripped, out newGuid))
{
    Console.WriteLine(newGuid.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("failed");
}
```

As you can see it generates a new guid, replaces all non valid characters with nothing and then creates a new guid from this.

This has some advantages in some ways. Unicode specifies a lot of different hyphens and if for some reason you get some of them this will work without you having to deal with each of them specifically (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode for examples of the multitude of hyphens). It will have the disadvantage that any string that contains exactly 32 valid characters, even if it is not anything like a guid will successfully parse.

Whether you use this or the more specific method largely depends on what your expectations are of how far from the standard your input is likely to be. If you can guarantee that it is only ever this one deviation from standard that you need to worry about then Ben Pretorius's answer is clearly the one. If you are getting input that might have other deviations but you know its always goingf to at least be an attempt at a guid then this might work.

If you expect people might use things like "Anna, call me on 01234 567890 or 07777 777 777 so we can chat. Mum." then you definitely don't want to use this method. That string will parse as a guid under my method. :)

Comment: I like your evil string.

Comment: @Rawling: It took me a while to craft it. I feel using two phone numbers was cheating a bit but I don't think it would have been as short and snappy without. :) More realistically though I really wanted to make sure I emphasised how badly wrong this had the potential to go if your input could be anything and needed an example for that.

Answer (score 2):

So a good practice would be to sanitize the string before attempting to parse it.

I use the following method and hope it helps out some people out there.

```
String strGUID = responseFromServer.Replace('\u2010', '\u002D');
```

this will replace the long hyphens with the required short ones to be used in the following way:

```
                    if (Guid.TryParseExact(strGUID , "D", out identifier))
                    {
                        ReportFile reportFile = this._reportFileService.FindByIdentifier(identifier);
                        if (reportFile != null)
                        {
                            fileBytes = reportFile.FileBytes;
                            fileName = reportFile.FileName;
                            success = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Failed to load ReportFile for Identifier: " + identifier);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: Rather than trying to replace invalid characters, you should extract the valid ones. Anyway, long hyphens aren't valid for GUIDs. This isn't a cross-platform issue, it's a bug on the other guy's code. GUIDs an

Comment: Well in my case I am creating guid's which are valid in use. However somewhere it is serialized to JSON inside a payload which is where the issue is happening.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Nobody ever said it wasn't a bug in the other code. Sometimes though you just have to deal with crap input as well as you can.